# Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system. Provide explicit type for 'list_of_coordinate_ids' of 'UpdateCoordinatesInput' class

Tags: typescript, api, graphql, typegraphql

This error is arising solely because of my incorrect usage of `list_of_coordinate_ids` as an "array of strings". Rest of the code is working fine.

This is the entity aka model file.

```
import { Entity, BaseEntity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn } from "typeorm";
import { ObjectType, Field, ID, Float } from "type-graphql";

@Entity("current_routes")
@ObjectType()
export class CurrentRoutes extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  unique_route_id:number;

  @Field(() => [String])
  @Column({type: "varchar", length: 45,array:true, default:[] })
  list_of_coordinate_ids:string[];
  
  @Field(() => Date)
  @CreateDateColumn()
  time_of_route_generation:Date;
  
  //TODO : Add as carriers_on_platform -> OneToMany -> current_routes
  @Field(()=>Number)
  @Column()
  carrier_id :number
}
```

this is the resolver file

```
import { Resolver, Query, Mutation, Arg } from "type-graphql";
import { Coordinates } from "../entity/Coordinate";
import { CurrentRoutes } from "../entity/CurrentRoutes";
import { CreateCoordinatesInput } from "../inputs/CoordinatesInputs/CreateCoordinatesInput";
import { UpdateCoordinatesInput } from "../inputs/CoordinatesInputs/UpdateCoordinatesInput";
import { CreateCurrentRoutesInput } from "../inputs/CurrentRoutesInput/CreateCurrentRoutesInput";

@Resolver()
export class CurrentRoutesResolver {
  @Query(() => [CurrentRoutes])
  allCurrentRoutes() {
    return CurrentRoutes.find()
  }
  @Mutation(() => CurrentRoutes)
  async createCurrentRoutes(@Arg("data") data: CreateCurrentRoutesInput) {
    const currentRoutes = CurrentRoutes.create(data);
    await currentRoutes.save();
    return currentRoutes;
  }
  @Query(() => CurrentRoutes)
    particularCurrentRoute(@Arg("unique_route_id") unique_route_id: string) {
      return CurrentRoutes.findOne({ where: { unique_route_id } });
  }
  @Mutation(() => CurrentRoutes)
  async updateCoordinates(@Arg("unique_route_id") unique_route_id: string, @Arg("data") data: UpdateCoordinatesInput) {
    const currentRoute = await CurrentRoutes.findOne({ where: { unique_route_id } });
    if (!currentRoute) throw new Error("Current route not found!");
    Object.assign(currentRoute, data);
    await currentRoute.save();
    return currentRoute;
  }
  @Mutation(() => CurrentRoutes)
  async deleteCoordinates(@Arg("unique_route_id") unique_route_id: string) {
    const currentRoute = await CurrentRoutes.findOne({ where: { unique_route_id } });
    if (!currentRoute) throw new Error("Current Route not found!");
    await currentRoute.remove();
    return currentRoute;
  }
}
```

these are the input files

```
import { InputType, Field } from "type-graphql";

@InputType()
export class CreateCurrentRoutesInput {
  @Field()
  list_of_coordinate_ids:string[]

  @Field()
  carrier_id:number;
}
```

```
import { InputType, Field } from "type-graphql";

@InputType()
export class UpdateCurrentRoutesInput {
  @Field({nullable:true})
  list_of_coordinate_ids?:string[]

  @Field({nullable:true})
  carrier_id?:number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should defined the types also in your input types

```
@InputType()
export class CreateCurrentRoutesInput {
  @Field(()=>[String]) <---see here
  list_of_coordinate_ids:string[]

  @Field()
  carrier_id:number;
}
```

same here

```
@InputType()
export class UpdateCurrentRoutesInput {
  @Field(()=>[String], {nullable:true})
  list_of_coordinate_ids?:string[]

  @Field({nullable:true})
  carrier_id?:number;
}
```

BTW it also seems to me that the typeorm column is not correct and might be type of array or simple-array ?

```
@Field(() => [String])
  @Column({
        type: "simple-array", 
        length: 45,
        default:[]
      }) 
  list_of_coordinate_ids:string[];
```